# How to fix bizarre crash in Chaco-based plotting app.?

Tags: python, chaco

I've got a really bizarre case: my Chaco-based Python GUI plotting application crashes, or doesn't, according to the comments in the code below:

```py
# self.ideal_signal = x             # Causes crash.
# self.ideal_signal = x[:-70000]    # Fixes crash.
# self.ideal_signal = x[:-62500]    # Causes crash again.
self.ideal_signal = 0.6 * x         # Also fixes crash
# self.ideal_signal = 0.7 * x       # Causes crash again.
```

`x` is a 256,000 element NumPy nd-array of type `float64`.

I have no idea what to do here.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

It's almost as if crash/don't crash is determined by the cumulative sum of the amplitude (magnitude?) of the signal being plotted, but that seems awfully silly.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a minimal reproducible example, if possible. This might lead you to the answer. If not, post the mimimal example at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ets-users